# When to use template engines (Like Jade/Haml/Slim)?

Tags: html, pug, template-engine

Usually when I convert PSD to HTML/CSS I use simple code editor (Sublime Text, Brackets) + emmet. Recently I tried to use Jade, because I've heard that it significantly speeds up the process, and it seems to me that it slows down the converting process. And here's an important detail - I usually convert one-page PSDs, so maybe Jade is more powerful when using for bigger projects?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please vist the [help] to see what and how to ask. Right now your question is off tpoic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of templates is to place content / markup / etc that are shared between multiple pages in a single place (mostly so that it doesn't need to be edited in multiple places when you change it).

If you are only creating a single page than using a template is pointless (unless that page has relatively complex sections of content that are repeated (e.g. a biographic profile consisting of a heading, an image, a list of data points, and some paragraphs of data, all wrapped in a collection of elements with certain classes applied to them).

The techniques you use to design the markup are immaterial.